# Field collection - Delete "Remove button" on line

Tags: users, entities

I need to delete the "Remove button" on every edit field collection for specific role users. I have 3 roles (Admin, Project, Test). Just Admin and project can see the "delete" button and "add" button to remove lines or add a new line. The others roles are not allowed to delete or add new line in the field collection.

I tried to change some permissions (Administer field collections - Create and delete fields on field collections.) But it didn't work...

I need to use HOOK ? or maybe just JQuery ?

To complete my explication, here an example :

[image: Field collection remove button "Supprimer"]

Thanks

PS : "Supprimer" = "Remove"

Comment: Hello. I removed dead link. There was no image under it. If you *need* to post image, use image tool on editor's toolbar here. But please do your best to *write* what you want, images should be only a supplement, not main content of your post. By [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), implementing a functionality for which only a screenshot is provided is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write following code in your theme template.php file. It will added css classes to body of a specfic page.

```
    <?php 

    function hook_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
      global $user;
      $args = arg();

        if( isset($args[0]) && ($args[0] ==  'your-page-url-first-argument')){ // Check ur page url parameters
        $account = user_load($user->uid);
        if(in_array("test", $account->roles)){
          $variables['classes_array'][] = 'test_user';
        }
      }?>
```

CSS:

```
.test_user [remove_button_class/id] {

  display:none

}
```